# Can I create sites and application pools on a remote IIS server using Powershell?

Tags: iis, powershell, web-administration

I have a Powershell script that sets up new web servers. At the moment, you have to connect to the server via Remote Desktop and run the script locally; it uses the `WebAdministration` module and is full of pseudopaths like IIS:/Sites\www.mysite.com\ and so on.

Can I use the same `WebAdministration` module to manage a remote server? I'd hoped something like `get-childitem IIS://myserver/Sites/` might work but can't find any documentation or examples of using this module against a remote server.

Answer (score 4):

What you do is set up powershell remoting (before you start with `WebAdministration` at all). This has to be configured on the remote server first though as it's not enabled by default.

You'll need to run `Enable-PSRemoting –force` while runing PS as admin to turn it on, and there's a few other minor bits to get the security sensible. There's a decent technet article on this at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx

Once you've done that, you can invoke a command on the remote machine using:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER -ScriptBlock { COMMAND } -credential USERNAME
```